# Specify parameter by name in PHP

Tags: php, parameter-passing

I have no idea what this is called, but I've seen PHP supports a cool parameter passing like:

```
function myFunc($required_value, $optional_value1 = 'default', $optional_value2 = 'default2'){

}
```

And then I'd be able to do:

```
myFunc('something', $optional_value2 = 'test');
```

So 2 questions in regards to this:

1. What is this technique called (for future references)?
2. Since what PHP version is it supported?

Comment: And sorry if this is a dupe, but since I don't know what the technique is called, I didn't really know what to search for.

Comment: Voted to close as duplicate.

Comment: @EduardLuca your example isn't setting the `$optional_value2` parameter. It's creating a local variable `$optional_value2` and setting its value to `test`, then it's passing `test` as the second argument which is `$optional_value1`, and it leaves the third argument `$optional_value2` as the default (`default2`). Have a look at my duplicate link, it shows how you can have flexible default parameters using an array that aren't dependent on the order.

Comment: I realized that later, as I stated in a comment in @Baba's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Am not sure what `you are able to do` but php does not support [Named Parameters](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/namedparameters) yet

Ruining

```
myFunc('something', $optional_value2 = 'test');
```

Does not mean `$optional_value2` would become 'test` in the function [See Demo](https://eval.in/37266)

What you are currently implementing is called [Default parameters](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php) in functions

Comment: I see. I think I know what I am doing, and why it's working. When passing the parameter, I'm actually assigning a value to a variable, which returns `true`. The `true` value is then passed to the function as the 2nd param. Mystery solved and yet another reason why PHP sucks comparative to Python.

Comment: PHP does not suck .. its Awesome if you only know what you are doing ... Same goes for every other language

Comment: If you want, we can move that discussion to the chat, but why I'm saying that, is because PHP is limited compared to other languages, so you may know what you are doing, but you still get 10 lines of code in PHP, while in other languages it could have been done in 2 lines.

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11/php .... you are fee to discus your options

Comment: This totally sucks vs Python

Answer (score 2):

its called [default parameters](http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/4/15/5).

In your exapmple. there is a slight mistake. given your function

```
function myFunc($required_value, $optional_value1 = 'default', $optional_value2 = 'default2'){
.....
}
```

you can call this in the following ways:

```
myFunc('required_value'); //$optional_value1 = 'default', $optional_value2 = 'default2'
myFunc('required_value', 'opt1'); //$optional_value2 = 'default2'
myFunc('required_value', 'opt1', 'op2');
```

thing to note is that php doesn't support named parameters, so there order is important. therefore, you can't omit middle params. so the following statements would be wrong because you are trying to use named parameters.

```
myFunc('something', $optional_value2 = 'test');
```

For more details, see [this](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php)

Answer (score 0):

The only think that comes to my mind is to pass arguments via array.

```
function f($params)
{ 
    if(!isset($params['name']) || !isset($params['adress'])) 
    {
        //trigger error throw exception or whatever
    }
    //do something with params
}
```

and calling

```
f(array('name' => 'asdfasdf', 'adress' => 'adfasdf'));
```

then in function you can check if there are enough params to process function.

PHP doesn't have named params like for example C#.

PHP support default values of parameters so you can use it for example:

```
 function f($name = "John Doe"){echo $name;}
```

when you call

```
echo f(); // John Doe will be displayed
echo f("Robert"); //Robert will be displayed
```

Answer (score 0):

this is Default Arguments

Important thing to note is that Optional parameters can only be specified in the last , so Required parameters come before the Optional parameters in the function definition e.g.

function myFunc($param1,$optional1= 'string',$optional2= 5)
{

}

while calling the function we can call it as

```
myFunc($param1);
myFunc($param1 , 'new string');
myFunc($param1,'string',10);
```

but not    myFunc($param1,10);
**skipping the middle argument is not allowed!!!**
The method you have used to call the func is wrong

In your example. there is a slight mistake. 
 you can't omit middle params. so the following function call

```
   myFunc('something', $optional_value2 = 'test');
```

is not allowed!
Further $optional_value2 = 'test' cannot appear in the function call...simply 'test' should be passed as an argument to the function.